# Uploading a image to AWS s3 in go - size is 0 bytes

Tags: go

I am trying to upload files to S3 with the following code:

[image: go program]

Following the upload the files in s3 are 0 bytes; why is this?
[image: screenshot showing S3 files]

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - copy and [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/11810946) the code

Comment: also show us what exactly `body` is. Is it possible that the body reader is already consumed?

Comment: Welcome! Try to provide a minimal working piece of code. For example, in your screenshot we cannot see where the variable `body` is defined and initialized.

Comment: Note that for Upload, `Body member is an io.Reader instead of an io.ReadSeeker` as it would be in PutObjectInput

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.